# Delphi 2010 Web Broker

Tags: delphi

I have a Delphi 7 Web broker app that is working perfectly.  I need to upgrade to Delphi 2010 because the web services in Delphi 7 doesn't work with the web service I need to consume.  When I compile and run it under Delphi 2010 i get "The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers" error. I'm guessing it is related to ansistring but cannot figure it out.

Any ideas on how I can solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Q: Are you sure you want an (older technology) "Web broker"?  Are you sure you don't have a (more modern) SOAP Web service, and a WSDL?

Comment: Did you read all about the Unicode changes?